# SyntaxError: non-keyword arg after keyword arg python

Tags: python, grass-gis, simulation

I'am working a project about hot clouds volcano mountain simulation with Titan2D v4.0.0 but I got error when I try to run the simulation.py

```
sim.setGIS(
   gis_format='GIS_GRASS',
   gis_main='/home/dinar/Downloads/titan2d-v4.0.0/grass',
   gis_sub='newLocation',
   gis_mapset='PERMANENT',
   gis_map='merapi8m.grass',
   gis_vector=None,
   region_limits==(417661e+05, 9143861e+06, 4611590e+05, 9176061e+06) 
)
```

it said non-keyword arg after keyword arg python

Comment: `region_limits` has a double equals sign (so it's checking for equality, evaluating to a boolean, and then passing in a bool after all of your kwargs).

Comment: Thanks, I didnt check that before

Answer (score 2):

It was a human error, I didn't check the syntax.
Here is the correct one

```
sim.setGIS(
       gis_format='GIS_GRASS',
       gis_main='/home/dinar/Downloads/titan2d-v4.0.0/grass',
       gis_sub='newLocation',
       gis_mapset='PERMANENT',
       gis_map='merapi8m.grass',
       gis_vector=None,
       region_limits=[4.17661e+05, 9.143861e+06, 4.611590e+05, 9.176061e+06] 
)
```